# Will creating a new folder break subversion?

Tags: svn

I have a subversion repository, but there are some things that I don't want it to mess with. For example, SVN breaks mac resource files because unix doesn't know about the resource fork.

However, I still want some form of back-up/version control. I would like to be able to just create a folder within the top level repository folder, and stick my stuff there. However, the readme.txt file in that folder says "don't touch this unless you know what you're doing".

So, is it safe to do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be incredibly nervous about doing this.

Whilst it may not actively break subversion immediately, subversion is going to assume that it has complete control of all the folders within the repository, and that it knows what they all are. If some tool, script or process performs some generic action across all the files, you could find your backups mangled and/or the repository corrupted.

And just because it doesn't break it in the current version, doesn't mean that it won't cause problems in the next. So basically - I'd really avoid doing this, it's makes everything really messy.

Answer (score 0):

You never ever should mess around with the repository folder directly.

Use an svn client and access the repository either via the file:/// url or set up a server (svn, apache) and then access the repository via svn:// or http(s)://.

And then you can create subfolders without any problems.

But I strongly recommend you read the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) first (available free online), since you seem lack some basic knowledge about repositories and how to properly use Subversion.

Comment: I understand how to use subversion for things that Iwant subversion to do. My question is whether I can put a folder in there that subversion will IGNORE. 

If I create the folder with a subversion client, it will add it to the repository, which is exactly what I DON'T want to do...

Comment: Why put it in the Subversion folder if you don't want Subversion to have anything to do with it? Why not just create a folder somewhere entirely differently on the file system? Anything in the virtual folder structure within Subversion is for VERSIONED resources.

Comment: I don't want it in the virtual folder structure. I justwant it in the top level folder so all of my backups / versions to save between programmers/ etc are all in one place. 

If I'd thought ahead, I could have created a super folder in which the svn folder lives, and used that, but it's too late...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.  I'm assuming that you want to have a backup folder that you just store under the svn repository path (file heirarchy).  I just tried it, it works fine.  Of course, it doesn't include the files in a svn manner -- just old fashioned file heirarchy.  This works if you want to save things like manual backups, or if your svn repo directory is actually on a RAIDed drive, for example.

Comment: Yeah, I want the files there in a normal file hierarchy sense, just so that its all in once place... I don't want things in an svn manner because that will break them...

Comment: Wait, was the short answer of "no" an answer to "will it break subversion?" or an answer to "is it safe?" (Bad Brian, don't ask yes/no questions with both sides of the question...)

Answer (score 0):

To add to Stefan's answer: Make sure you understand the difference between the repository location (which holds the database and configuration for that repository) and the virtual folder structure that Subversion presents to users.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to use the virtual folder structure at all for this.